# make: Nothing to be done for 'exit_status.c'

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, makefile, cs50

I cannot compile any of the codes I wrote. Whenever i type 'make' the error message is:

```
make: Nothing to be done for '*FILE*'
```

In addition to the problem, `cs50.h` is always underlined red.

I'm using visual studio code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>


int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Error code argccount!2");
        return 1; // 1 signals to the computer that something went wrong
    }

    print("Hello %s\n", argv[1])
    return 0; // 0 indicates that all went well
}
```

At first the make command wasn't recognizable in the terminal. So I manage to install it after watching a youtube video. Whenever i call make it comes but then it doesn't just work like how the lecturer's machine does.

This is my terminal text:

> ```
> PS C:\Users\`~d L n\Desktop\Folders\CS50> make exit_status.c
> make: Nothing to be done for 'exit_status.c'.
> PS C:\Users\`~d L n\Desktop\Folders\CS50> make exit_stat
> make: *** No rule to make target 'exit_stat'.  Stop.
> PS C:\Users\`~d L n\Desktop\Folders\CS50> make foo
> make: *** No rule to make target 'foo'.  Stop.
> PS C:\Users\`~d L n\Desktop\Folders\CS50>
> ```

Following the last comment, I realized the it was better to get a linux environment. So I installed linux with ubuntu feature. My interface looks much more similar to that of the professor who is teaching the cs50 course on Youtube. Installation of make was also successful. However, I'm encountering another problem:

dillon@OPTIMUS:~$ make hello_world
cc     hello_world.c   -o hello_world
make: cc: No such file or directory
make: *** [: hello_world] Error 127

I added the path to my system path, but it still didn't solve the problem. The path I added was the path of the hello_world.c file

Comment: Please show your make command. I expect you typed `make exit_status.c`, which is wrong.

Comment: Is that back-tick before `int main` actually there?

Comment: The file you give to `make` on the command line is the target you want make to _create_.  It's not the source file you want to use to create it.  `make foo.c` tells make "please create me a file named `foo.c`" and make sees that file already exists, and doesn't know of any way to update it, so it says "nothing to do".  If you want to create a program, like `foo`, you say `make foo` then make will try to create that for you.

Comment: if cs50.h is in the local path, you want to use #include "cs50.h" instead.

Comment: You want to share your command (eg., `make myTarget`) and your Makefile content (which should contain your target for make, eg., `myTarget:` etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a `Makefile` file, without which, `make` does not know what to do.

Example:

```
exit_status: exit_status.o
    cc exit_status.o -o exit_status

exit_status.o: exit_status.c
    cc -c exit_status.c -o exit_status.o
```

Which is, in pseudo code:

```
target : requirements
    command using requirements to create target
```

only then you can expect something from `make target`.
Now you can execute the command `make exit_status`.

More to read: https://makefiletutorial.com/

Comment: @ Soleil, thanks for the suggestions. I'm new to coding so I'm finding it a bit difficult to understand what you suggested. However, the tutorial link you provided is proving to be of great help

Comment: @HenryDillon What exactly you do not get fully ? In a nut shell, I gave you the content of the needed file (Makefile), so you can run a make command (`make exit_status`) successfully.

Comment: I now get it. But I've gotten another problem also. 

cc     exit_status.c   -o exit_status
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cc exit_status.c -o exit_status, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [<builtin>: exit_status] Error 2
PS C:\Users\`~d L n\Desktop\Folders\CS50>

Comment: @HenryDillon It seems that you are running from powershell. make usually (in GNU/Linux) is an alias to gmake, which is not present in Windows, only WSL, but then you are compiling for a Linux kernel. With Windows, there is nmake (not installed by default). So the simplest is to run WSL (bash) and run your command. Or from powershell `bash -c "make exit_status"`. Usually when you have another question, you ask another question, you don't chain them in comments; but I guess this time it's OK.

Comment: @HenryDillon Usually if you are using gnu tools, you better live in a gnu environment (gnu linux). With Windows, you use WSL or you switch completely to Visual Studio, which has aids to target linux too. You can do that with vscode too, but that's really another question.

Comment: That error means that make tried to run the `cc` program and it couldn't be found.

Comment: Yeah you are right @MadScientist.